# Google Custom Search Api Daily Limit Exceeded Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-custom-search

I'm using Google Custom Search API. Currently in free service plan which allow us upto 10K queries each day.

I used so far under 5K queries, and still about 5K queries quota left for today, but for some reason i'm getting your maximum daily limit exceeded error [403 response].

FYI: I'm using API in windows form application, it worked fine till yesterday.

Any clues how to get this problem fixed? Any Help Appreciated Cheers!

Comment: Can you please give us the URL for your free service plan's quotas?  I'm not familiar with any free service we offer at 10k queries/day so I can't help directly; however all plans I do know have other quotas for free service beyond max number per day so I imagine you must be bumping up against  such other quotas. What dashboard (or what else?) do you use to track your quota usage?  Where does GAE enter the picture?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply, Yep, I'm in 10k queries/day in 5$/1k rate. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview. I'm seeing cse quota usage is 5K, still seeing remaining quoto for the day, but api keeps giving the same error. We have utilized yesterday 10K limit, I'm assuming the Limit reset at GMT?